# Is my cable modem/router flakey, or is it the upstream connection?

Tags: networking, router, ping, cable-modem

Our internet connection goes down on an average of twice an hour.  There doesn't seem to be a consistency about when.
We have a Motorola MG7540 Cable Modem/Router (at 10.0.0.1) that provides both wired and wifi connections.
I've set up one of my machines that's connected via wire to constantly ping (every five seconds):

1. The router (10.0.0.1)
2. The internet (via 8.8.8.8)
3. Another machine on the network.  Note that the machine running the test and this second machine are both connected via wire to the same access point, so the ping isn't going through the (possibly problematic) router.  So this is probably a useless test.

The results from #3 are fine--pings never get interrupted.
But the pings to #1 and #2 get interrupted at the same time for every incident.

So, the question is:  Can we tell from this whether the problem is the modem or the upstream connection?  If not, what other information do I need to collect to discriminate between those two possible sources of error?
Thanks!

Comment: Take the failed ping tests (preferably when the outage is occurring) and report them to your ISP. They should be able to see the issue and then take corrective action - their gear or local connection issues outside your home/office

Comment: Is your ISP renting you the cable modem or do you own it? If they rent it to you, they are 100% responsible to maintain it and replace it if 1) or 2) occurs.

Comment: So the two machines pinging each other are both wired directly to the Motorola MG7540? Or are they both wired to some other AP?

Comment: Lol I don't see any results at all!

Comment: @Spiff They are both wired to an access point that is itself wired to the router.

Comment: @K7AAY I own the modem, hence my trying to figure out if it's my problem or theirs.